# What datatype should I use when adding a column that will contain a null to a Datatable with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a client that is sending this data:

```
{"answers":[
   {"response":true},
   {"response":true},
   {"response":true},
   {"response":false},
   {"response":false}]}
```

I have classes like this:

```
public class AnswerRow
{
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerRowList
{
    public IList<AnswerRow> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

In my WebAPI I receive the data like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("MarkQuestion/{testQuestionId}/{questionUId:Guid}")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MarkQuestion(string testQuestionId, Guid questionUId, [FromBody]AnswerRowList answer)
    {
        var createdBy = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        DataTable answers = new DataTable();
        answers.Columns.Add("Response", typeof(????));
        foreach (AnswerRow a in answer.Answers)
        {
            answers.Rows.Add(a.Response);
        }
```

I think all my code is okay except I do not know how to add a column to a DataTable that will accept a boolean. I tried BIT and Bit and bit but it shows a syntax error in VS2013 for these types.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the variable TinyInt instead of a boolean. This is a one byte datatype that you can use to enter values 1 or 0 if you'd like, to represent true and false, respectively. There may be other ways, but this is what I've used in my tables.

[Here's an MSDN article that explains some of the data types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how I utilized TinyInt last time. I would recommend changing your type to INT, and by convention only using values 1 or 0. So you can take your code here:

```
    answers.Columns.Add("Response", typeof(????));
    foreach (AnswerRow a in answer.Answers)
    {
        answers.Rows.Add(a.Response);
    }
```

And make it:

```
answers.Columns.Add("Response", typeof(int));
foreach(AnswerRow a in answer.Answers)
{
    if(a.Response) // Here I'm trying to check if a.Response is true
        answers.Rows.Add(1);
    else
        answers.Rows.Add(0);
}
```

I don't have the opportunity to test this at the moment, so let me know if it at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually it seems like TinyInt cannot be found so I am thinking I need to include a Using to the c# file.

Comment: Oh, hm. I will have to dig up some old source code but I opened my MySQL workbench to check and I had used the tinyint. Perhaps in your c# code you could cast a variable to [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of BIT? Or, if you can't find any other way, you can also use a regular int and again, use values of 1 or 0.

Comment: As a sidenote, I SELDOM use boolean for a db column. There are few things that have no possibility of being "extended" in the future to something besides only true/false.  I default to SmallInt, but a TinyInt would be better than a (only) true/false, IMHO.  This is to add to the argument to the McAdam...for this approach.